# HP 1820-8G (J9979A) user name

Tags: networking, switch

The HP switch 1820-8G (J9979A) has a web UI that allows configuration of VLANs, mirroring port etc. The manual says:

[image: HP 1820 manual]

But the website of the switch also requires a user name.

What is the user name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed Quick Start Guide which ships with the switch does not contain that information. This may be related to similar older products like the 1810-8G which did not need a user name to log in.

Looking at the full 110 page [HP 1820 Switches Management and Configuration Guide](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=7687976&docId=emr_na-c04622710&docLocale=en_US), you'll find that the user name is `admin`.